# Comparing counts from two tables based on a date column

Tags: sql, count, union

I have two tables with date columns in them. I want to count the number of rows grouped by that date column and see which dates don’t match the count of the other table + show the difference.

Ex.
Table 1

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apr. 25 | 178048 |
| Apr. 24 | 36273 |

Table 2

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apr. 25 | 178048 |
| Apr. 24 | 36073 |

Wanted results:

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apr. 24 | 200 |

I tried to do minus query and union all but it doesn’t work.

```
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM table1
group by 1 order by 1 desc
MINUS
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM table2
group by 1 order by 1 desc
UNION ALL
(
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM table2
group by 1 order by 1 desc
MINUS
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM table1
group by 1 order by 1 desc
)
```

Please help a beginner out thank you

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MINUS is called EXCEPT in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining the summarised tables by date; using full outer join to allow for dates missing from one or the other:

```
select coalesce(Tbl1.dte, tbl2.dte) as dte
, coalesce(Tbl1.cnt,0)-coalesce(tbl2.cnt,0) as diff
from 
    (SELECT dte, count() cnt
    FROM table1 
    group by dte) Tbl1
    full outer join
    (SELECT dte, count() cnt
    FROM table2
    group by dte) Tbl2
    on tbl1.dte=tbl2.dte
```

I used `dte`, instead of `date`, because that maybe a reserved word in your dbms (you didn't tag it).

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` the tables, and then `GROUP BY` the result. Use `HAVING` to only return dates where the tables' number of rows are different.

```
select "date", sum(c1) - sum(c2)
from
(
    SELECT "date", 1 as c1, 0 as c2
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "date", 0, 1
    FROM table2
) as dt
group by "date"
having sum(c1) <> sum(c2)
```